# how to open the document on double clicking a row from jtable list obtained from database

Tags: java

The JFilechooser chooses the document which I want to upload in the database , the selected filename goes to the database and the file in a folder and also I can show the database table in my jtable through gui now what i need to do is when I double click the row of any table I want the document to be opened.How will I do this?

```
//code to attach the document to a folder and its name to the database

    private void add_newActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                          
try {
JFileChooser selectedFile = new JFileChooser();
int a = selectedFile.showOpenDialog(null);
File file = selectedFile.getSelectedFile();
Path dscPath = Paths.get(Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath()+ "\\store\\"+file.getName());
Path path = Files.copy(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), dscPath  ,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

SqlFunctions sql = new SqlFunctions();
sql.StoreFileName(file.getName());

System.out.println("File uploaded is "+file.getName());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

//code to populate jtable data from database
private void Update_table(){
    try{

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/uploader","root","");
String sql="select * from files";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);
table_documentinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

}

//method to store file name in database

```
 public void StoreFileName(String fileName){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO files VALUES ("+null+",'"+fileName+"')";
   // String sql = "insert into files(fileName) "+ "values(?)";
    System.out.println(sql);

    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+ex.getMessage() );
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

}
And I have not implemented the code for mouseclick event to open the document directly

Comment: Can we please see your code? Please do not ask us to do your homework.

Comment: //code to populate jtable data from database
private void Update_table(){
    try{
        
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/uploader","root","");
    String sql="select * from files";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery(sql);
    table_documentinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

apply some logic for double click.

use something like flag which will be 1 after 1st click n 2 after second click. And open the document only if flag = 2.

you can use mouse listener for this.